# REGEX / replace only works once

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using REGEX and js replace to dynamically populate a variable in a href. The following code works the first time it is used on the page, but if a different variable is passed to the function, it does not replace ANYTHING.

```
function change(fone){
    $("a[href^='/application']").each(function(){ 
        this.href = this.href.replace(/device=.*/,"device="+ fone);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `this.href` actually returns a full absolute URL.  So even your HTML is `<a href="/foo">` the `.href` property will return `http://mydomain.com/foo`.

So your href attributes is being populated with a full absolute URL, and then the `a[href^='/application']` selector doesn't match anymore, because the href attribute starts with the domain name, instead of `/application`.

Answer (score 1):

`.href` returns a fully qualified URL, e.g. `http://www.mydomain.com/application/...'. So the selector doesn't work the 2nd time around since your domain relative URL has been replaced with a full URL, and it's looking for things that *start* with "/application".

Use `$(this).attr('href').replace...` instead.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pcm5K/3/

Answer (score 1):

As Squeegy says, you're changing the `href` the first time around so it no longer begins with `/application` - the second time around it begins with `http://`.

You can use the [jQuery Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to get the links, and it's probably also better practice to use a capture group to do the replacement.  Like so:

```
$("a[href*='/application']").each(function(){
     this.href = this.href.replace(/(device=)\w*/, "$1" + fone);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the `g` flag to [match all instances of the pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp), so your regular expression will look like this:

```
/device=.*/g
```

and your code will look like:

```
this.href = this.href.replace(/device=.*/g,"device="+ fone);
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference - he's calling the regex for each `a` and only needs one match time.

Comment: That doesn't fix it. The .each function takes care of the global instruction

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that unless all you links start as "/device=." the regex wont work.

```
you need to use /.*device=.*/
```

the lack of global flag is not the problem. its the backslash in your pattern.